# Get values from formatted, delimited string with quoted labels and values

Tags: php, regex, linux

I have an input string like this:

`"Day":June 8-10-2012,"Location":US,"City":Newyork`

I need to match 3 value substrings:

`June 8-10-2012`

`US`

`Newyork`

I don't need the labels.

Comment: Is this JSON? It looks like poorly formed JSON...

Comment: You can use `(?<=:)[^,]+`

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What about [preg_split](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), successively on `,` then `:`? Otherwise I'll rely on @ctwheels answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above, if this is JSON, you should definitely use those functions as they are more suited for this.

However, you can use the following REGEX.

`/:([a-zA-Z0-9\s-]*)/g`

```
<?php
preg_match('/:([a-zA-Z0-9\s-]*)/', '"Day":June 8-10-2012,"Location":US,"City":Newyork', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The regex demo is here:

https://regex101.com/r/BbwVQ5/1

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of simple ways:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/22goi))

```
$string = '"Day":June 8-10-2012,"Location":US,"City":Newyork';

var_export(preg_match_all('/:\K[^,]+/', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'fail');

echo "\n\n";

var_export(preg_split('/,?"[^"]+":/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'June 8-10-2012',
  1 => 'US',
  2 => 'Newyork',
)

array (
  0 => 'June 8-10-2012',
  1 => 'US',
  2 => 'Newyork',
)
```

[Pattern #1 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LeuESb/1)  `\K` restarts the match after `:` so that a positive lookbehind can be avoided (saving "steps" / improving pattern efficiency)  By matching all following characters that are not a comma, a capture group can be avoided (saving "steps" / improving pattern efficiency).

[Patter #2 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LeuESb/2) `,?` makes the comma optional and qualifies the leading double-quoted "key" to be matched (split on).  The targeted substring to split on will match the full "key" substring and end on the following `:` colon.